# Poincaré sections does not work

Tags: plotting

These are the equations for  Poincaré sections:

```
    M = 0.5; a = 0.2; s = 0.1;M = 1/2; Δ = r^2 - 2*M*r[t] + a^2;
    W = r[t]^2 + a^2*Cos[θ[t]]^2;
    h = s*M^3*r[t]/W^2;
    gtt = -Simplify[(1 - 2*M*r[t]/W)*(1 + h)];
    grr = Simplify[W (1 + h)/(Δ + a^2*Sin[θ[t]]^2*h)];
    gss = W;
    gff = Simplify[(r[t]^2 + a^2 + 2 a^2*M*r[t]*Sin[θ[t]]^2/W)*
    Sin[θ[t]]^2 + h*a^2*Sin[θ[t]]^4*(1 + 2*M*r[t]/W)]
    gtf = -2*a*M*r[t]*Sin[θ[t]]^2*(1 + h)/W
    L = 1/2 (gtt*en^2 + grr*D[r[t], t]^2 + gss*D[θ[t], t]^2 + 
    gff*ln^2 + 2 gtf*en*ln);
```

I would like to plot the Poincaré section for collection of (`r[t]`, `Derivative[1][r][t]`), I wrote:

```
   date = Block[{en = 0.95, ln = 1.5}, 
   Reap[NDSolve[{grr*(r^′′)[t] == 
   D[L, r[t]] - D[grr, r[t]]*Derivative[1][r][t]^2 - 
    D[grr, θ[t]]*Derivative[1][r][t]*
     Derivative[1][θ][t], 
  gss*(θ^′′)[t] == 
   D[L, θ[t]] - 
    D[gss, θ[t]]*Derivative[1][θ][t]^2 - 
    D[gss, r[t]]*Derivative[1][r][t]*Derivative[1][θ][t], 
  r[0] == 8, θ[0] == Pi/2,
  WhenEvent[Derivative[1][r][0] == 0, 
   Sow[{r[t], Derivative[1][r][t]}]]}, {}, {t, 100000}, 
 MaxSteps -> ∞]]][[-1, 1]]; ListPlot[data, 
ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0025]]
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question contain `(r^′′)[t]` and `(θ^′′)[t]`, which are, I presume, transcription errors.  They should be `r''[t]` and `θ''[t]`.  With these corrections, the code contains two errors.  First, `Δ` should be given by

```
Δ = r[t]^2 - 2*M*r[t] + a^2
```

Second, values for `r'[0]`and `θ'[0]` must be provided to `NDSolve`.  For all values of `r'[0]`and `θ'[0]` that I have tried, `r[t]` grows exponentially, and at most one value of `{r[t], r'[t]}` is returned by `WhenEvent`.  So, for instance, with `r'[0] == -10, θ'[0] == -2`, one obtains (with `{}` replaced by `{r[t], θ[t]}` in `NDSolve` and `[[-1, 1]]` removed),

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[{r[t], θ[t]} /. date[[1, 1]]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

shows that `r[t]` grows exponentially and `θ[t]` becomes constant after only a single oscillation.  Thus,

```
date[[-1, 1]]
(* {{6.96449, 1.87522*10^-12}} *)
```

Perhaps a better choice for `r'[0]`and `θ'[0]` would yield an oscillatory solution, but finding it is not trivial.